# How do I check to see if a file exists on a remote server using shell

Tags: shell

I have done a lot of searching and I can't seem to find out how to do this using a shell script.  Basically, I am copying files down from remote servers and I want to do something else if it doesn't exist.  I have an array below, but I tried to reference it directly, but it is still returning false.

I am brand new at this, so please be kind :)

```
declare -a array1=('user1@user1.user.com');

for i in "${array1[@]}"
do
   if [ -f "$i:/home/user/directory/file" ];
   then
     do stuff
   else
     Do other stuff
   fi
done
```

Comment: you see, you cannot just connect to another host and check files, you need to ssh to it first or have some kind of NFS configured

Comment: You could just try the transfer and respond to the `scp` error code for file does not exist (or other error condition). Assuming you are using `scp` that is.

Comment: Do you need to do something locally or on the remote machine in those two cases?

Comment: Lashane - Considering I am brand new, that isn't really helpful  EtanReisner - That would work, too.  I can search for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using `scp` and `ssh` for remote connections something like this should do what you want.

```
declare -a array1=('user1@user1.user.com');

for i in "${array1[@]}"; do
    if ssh -q "$i" "test -f /home/user/directory/file"; then
        scp "$i:/home/user/directory/file" /local/path
    else
        echo 'Could not access remote file.'
    fi
done
```

Alternatively, if you don't necessarily need to care about the difference between the remote file not existing and other possible `scp` errors then the following would work.

```
declare -a array1=('user1@user1.user.com');

for i in "${array1[@]}"; do
    if ! scp "$i:/home/user/directory/file" /local/path; then
        echo 'Remote file did not exist.'
    fi
done
```

Comment: AH!  Thank you so much!!  I used the first solution because I need to do more than what the second option seems to allow and it seems to be working on the first run through.  I am going to add it to the full script and try it out.

Comment: **It Worked!!**  Doing the happy dance now.  Thank you so much :)

Comment: If you need to do something when the `scp` succeed just add an `else` block to the second one or invert the logic (remove the `!`) and use the `else` block for the failure case.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
ssh -q $HOST [[ -f $i:/home/user/directory/file ]] && echo "File exists" || echo "File does not exist";
```

or like this:

```
if ssh $HOST stat $FILE_PATH \> /dev/null 2\>\&1
then
  echo "File exists"
else
  echo "File not exist"
fi
```

Comment: Quotes around that are going to be necessary.

Comment: Also `$i` here appears to be the host in question so that should be split off from the path and used in the `ssh` command.

Comment: I tried that and it still returns false for all cases.

Comment: @Brandy:- Updated with one more approach!